# Convert from string to date type in SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008

For example:
I let the user inputs date by

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server" Width="200px" Text = "20110815"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender" runat="server" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" PopupButtonID="date"
TargetControlID="date" Format="yyyyMMdd" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

The problem is that in my stored procedure, i tried using that string as a date type

```
@StartDate nvarchar(8),
@StartDate_int int =0
AS

BEGIN
select  @StartDate_int=CAST(convert(varchar(12),DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,0,@StartDate),0),112) as int)
select * from table where date(has int type)// = @StartDate_int

END
```

When I tried testing that stored procedure in MS Server management studio, I defined the parameter for @StartDate = 20110101 and the stored procedure did return all the corrected rows, but when i tried using stored procedure in my asp.net project, set @StartDate  parameter to string in the text-box, it didn't return any row.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SelectSpecificTimeSheet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="user" Name="UserName" 
            SessionField="loginState" Type="String"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter DefaultValue="20110815" ControlID="date" Name="StartDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate_int" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Can somebody show me what i did wrong :(

Comment: Why is your stored procedure performing the conversion instead of the calling code?

Comment: ah i'm learning sql-server thus i want to do the conversion by sql

Comment: thank everyone, when i tried binding data to the girdview manually , it worked

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

1. You can use Sql Profiler to see what data come to Sql server (Microsoft Sql Profiler for Enterprise Sql Server or [AnjLab Sql Profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) for Sql Server Express)
2. Create separate class to make calls to sql server (repository/data
   manager layer) and use  to access your data
   manager - in this way you'll always can control what is going on
   there

Answer (score 0):

http://linesofcode.net/snippets/45

Have a look at these examples. Would be a good idea to capture input to SQL Server using Sql Profiler as @cheburek suggests so you know what your server page is passing to the RDBMS.